# LibSVM and non-numerical data

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, categorization, document-classification

I'm interested in doing text categorization using LibSVM. How do you recommend I convert the terms/words to numerical data, so LibSVM can understand it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In text categorization people tend to build histograms of the words used in the domain, sometimes they look at combinations of two words and put that in their histogram (this are called bigrams). But it really depends on your data and your objectives.

Comment: My problem isn't the feature selection, but the actual encoding into the LibSVM format, which needs to be numerical. In their web site they mention a text categorization example, and make a comment about the proprocessing: "We use binary term frequencies and normalize each instance to unit length". What are 'binary term frequencies'?

Comment: Binary term frequencies are like binary histograms if some term appears or not in the article. You have a bunch of terms predefined, then you scan the article for those terms and the output is a 1/0 vector.

Comment: Your right, I was having trouble finding where the actual feature (the string) would be stored. But looking at the file format: '[id,]label fid1:fval1 fid2:fval2 ....', its the fid.
Thanks!